# Apex Trigger to Update Feed Comment

Tags: apex, trigger, feeditem, chatter-feed-tracking, feedcomment

I am new to Apex Triggers. I have a checkbox field in Opportunity called "Opportunity Approved?". Currently as soon as user selects the checkbox, its adding a feed comment like this,

```
Opportunity approved?
false to true
```

I want to change this to some meaningful comment like `"Opportunity Approved is changed from false to true by {{user name}}"`. How can I write trigger for this or is there any way to achieve this?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option

- Turn off Chatter Feed tracking for this `Opportunity_Approved__c` field in your Feed Tracking settings. That will eliminate the message you are currently getting
- Add a Flow that detects the change to the `Opportunity_Approved__c`. Have the Flow do a Core Action `Chatter Post` where you can customize the message to your desire.